# JBOSS Migration AS6 to EAP 7 404 Error

Tags: jboss, wildfly

This question is Not Answered.(Mark as assumed answered)
 Andy Gowdy
Newbie
Andy Gowdy 31-Mar-2017 06:56
HI

I am having difficulty referencing an ear file after I have deployed it in EAP 7.  I have no deployment errors but when I try to access the the ear /beans through the URL I get a 404 error.  In the now deprecated JBOSS.xml  the URI was configured as shown.   Any help would be much appreciated.  Many Thanks Andy

```
<jboss>
  <enterprise-beans>
  <session>
  <ejb-name>HousingFacadeEJB</ejb-name>
  <jndi-name>HousingFacadeEJB</jndi-name>
  <local-jndi-name>LocalHousingFacadeEJB</local-jndi-name>
  <call-by-value>false</call-by-value>
  <!-- <configuration-name>Facade</configuration-name> -->
  <clustered>false</clustered>
            <port-component>
                <port-component-name>HousingFacade</port-component-name>
                <port-component-uri>HousingFacade/HousingFacadeEJB
                </port-component-uri>
            </port-component>
  </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
  <container-configurations>
  <container-configuration extends="Standard Stateless SessionBean">
      <container-name>HousingFacade</container-name>
  <container-pool-conf>
      <MinimumSize>50</MinimumSize>
  <MaximumSize>150</MaximumSize>
      </container-pool-conf>
  </container-configuration>
  </container-configurations>
</jboss>

----------------------------------------------------------

I have replaced this with a JBOSS-EJB3.xml

<enterprise-beans>
  <session>
   <ejb-name>HousingFacadeEJB2_Live</ejb-name>

   <home>com.comino.cxm.housingfacade.HousingFacadeHome</home>
   <remote>com.comino.cxm.housingfacade.HousingFacade</remote>
   <local-home>com.comino.cxm.housingfacade.LocalHousingFacadeHome</local-home>
   <local>com.comino.cxm.housingfacade.LocalHousingFacade</local>

   <ejb-class>com.comino.cxm.housingfacade.HousingFacadeBean</ejb-class>

   <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
   <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
   <env-entry>
                <env-entry-name>UHDSJNDINAME</env-entry-name>
                  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                  <env-entry-value>java:/UHTLIVE_2</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>

  </session>
  </enterprise-beans>

<assembly-descriptor>
  <container-transaction>
           <method>
             <ejb-name>HousingFacadeEJB2_Live</ejb-name>
  <method-name>*</method-name>
           </method>
           <trans-attribute>Required</trans-attribute>
        </container-transaction>
</assembly-descriptor>
```

---

My ejb-jar.xml

```
<jboss:ejb-jar>

  <enterprise-beans>
   <session>
   <ejb-name>HousingFacadeEJB2_Live</ejb-name>

   <home>com.comino.cxm.housingfacade.HousingFacadeHome</home>
   <remote>com.comino.cxm.housingfacade.HousingFacade</remote>
   <local-home>com.comino.cxm.housingfacade.LocalHousingFacadeHome</local-home>
   <local>com.comino.cxm.housingfacade.LocalHousingFacade</local>

   <ejb-class>com.comino.cxm.housingfacade.HousingFacadeBean</ejb-class>

   <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
   <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
   <env-entry>
              <env-entry-name>UHDSJNDINAME</env-entry-name>
              <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
              <env-entry-value>java:/UHTLIVE_2</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>

  </session>
  </enterprise-beans>

  <assembly-descriptor>
  <container-transaction>
           <method>
             <ejb-name>HousingFacadeEJB2_Live</ejb-name>
  <method-name>*</method-name>
           </method>
           <trans-attribute>Required</trans-attribute>
        </container-transaction>
  </assembly-descriptor>

</jboss:ejb-jar>
```

JBOSS Server log extract.. I have redacted the connection addresses.

----------------------------REQUEST---------------------------

```
URI=/HousingFacade2_Live/HousingFacadeEJB2_Live
characterEncoding=null
     contentLength=1304
       contentType=[text/xml; charset=utf-8]
            header=Connection=Keep-Alive
            header=SOAPAction=""
            header=Cache-Control=no-cache
            header=Content-Type=text/xml; charset=utf-8
            header=Content-Length=1304
            header=User-Agent=W2
            header=Host=**************
            locale=[]
            method=POST
          protocol=HTTP/1.1
       queryString=
        remoteAddr=*************
        remoteHost=************
            scheme=http
              host=*******************
        serverPort=8080
--------------------------RESPONSE--------------------------
     contentLength=74
       contentType=text/html
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=X-Powered-By=Undertow/1
            header=Server=JBoss-EAP/7
            header=Content-Length=74
            header=Content-Type=text/html
            header=Date=Fri, 31 Mar 2017 10:31:43 GMT
            status=404
==============================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

There are migration guide available, below are the two links where you can find the configuration how to migrate EJB application to JBoss EAP 7;

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/migration_guide/

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/developing_ejb_applications/

Comment: Thanks Anup - I have checked the documents and have reviewed the ear settings and code made slight adjust as shown but still get 404 errors. I am not using maven and don't have a pom file.                                                             final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
   jndiProperties.put(InitialContext.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
   initialContext = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
  // initialContext = new InitialContext();
   cache = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());